# Firebase Crashlytics IllegalStateException in SyncAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android

Ever since I updated to Firebase Crashlytics from Fabric, the app crashes at `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()` inside of the SyncAdapter. It works fine in the main app though. The error is a vague "java.lang.IllegalStateException".

Has anyone seen this or have any thoughts on what to do to fix it?

Comment: did you find any solution

Comment: Nope, it was coming from my background service and I just had to try/catch inside of my helper code